# Improve my Draggable DIV

Tags: javascript, css, html, draggable

Can anyone can help me to improve this draggable DIV? In the first drag/drop, all runs perfect. But when I try to drag for the 2nd time, the position bugs.

**CSS**

```
#coordenadas {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: rgb(224, 224, 224);
}
#clicado {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 0px;
    background: rgb(224, 224, 224);
}
#janela {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: rgb(224, 224, 224);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var clicado = false;
var inicioX;
var inicioY;
var finalX;
var finalY;

document.onmousemove = function mostrarInfo(event) {
    if (clicado == true) {
        finalX = event.clientX;
        finalY = event.clientY;
        pontoX = finalX - inicioX;
        pontoY = finalY - inicioY;
        document.getElementById('janela').style.top = pontoY + "px";
        document.getElementById('janela').style.left = pontoX + "px";
        document.getElementById('coordenadas').innerHTML = "X: " + pontoX + " | ";
        document.getElementById('coordenadas').innerHTML += "Y: " + pontoY;
    }
}

function segurar(event) {
    clicado = true;
    document.getElementById('clicado').innerHTML = "Mouse: Segurando";
    inicioX = event.clientX;
    inicioY = event.clientY;
}

function soltar() {
    clicado = false;
    document.getElementById('clicado').innerHTML = "Mouse: Solto";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="janela" onmousedown="segurar(event);" onmouseup="soltar();"></div>
<span id="coordenadas"></span>
<span id="clicado"></span>
```

Comment: You will most likely want to setup a JSFiddle of your code to demonstrate the behavior.

Comment: Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85xSM/) of the above.

Comment: use === in `clicado === true`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you're calculating the new position of your `<div>`. In your code, you are taking your mouse position and subtracting the initial position. This is OK for the first time around, because your initial position is `top: 0; left: 0`. But once you start moving it the second time it becomes more obvious. You're setting the position to the distance *between* your start position and your end position.

Change your `mostrarInfo` like this:

```
document.onmousemove = function mostrarInfo(event) {
    if (clicado == true) {
        pontoX = event.clientX;
        pontoY = event.clientY;
        document.getElementById('janela').style.top = pontoY + "px";
        document.getElementById('janela').style.left = pontoX + "px";
        document.getElementById('coordenadas').innerHTML = "X: " + pontoX + " | ";
        document.getElementById('coordenadas').innerHTML += "Y: " + pontoY;
    }
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZzWL/).

It is still not perfect, because it's trying to set the top-left corner of the `<div>` to your mouse position, but it is still better than your other one. To make it more exact, I suggest using something like JQuery instead. (Or else you'd need to figure out where in the `<div>` the click is happening, find the distance between that point and the top-left corner, and adjust your `pontoX` and `pontoY` accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the current position of the div to your offset since the mousedown event gives you global coordinates.

```
function segurar(event) {
    clicado = true;
    document.getElementById('clicado').innerHTML = "Mouse: Segurando";
    inicioX = event.clientX - document.getElementById('janela').offsetLeft;
    inicioY = event.clientY - document.getElementById('janela').offsetTop;
}
```

[here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CzsMt/)